# Rounding numbers to not be 1

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

I have a dataset that contains numbers very close to 1, but not actually 1:

```
library(dplyr)
Data <- tibble(Number = c(0.998971282, 0.97871, 0.98121752874, 0.98921752874, 0.91571358, 1))
```

It is important that any value that isn't actually 1 is not shown as being 1 in my output i.e. what happens when you use `round`:

```
Data %>% mutate(Rounded = round(Number))
```

Instead an output to two decimal places like this is required:

```
Data %>% mutate(Desired = c(0.99, 0.98, 0.98, 0.99, 0.92, 1.00))
```

Comment: What .00 means here? 1.00 or 0.00? in R it means 0. Why 1.0 turns to 0?

Comment: try `round(Number,2)`

Comment: What does "not exactly 1" mean to you? Should 0.999999999999999999999 be shown as 0.99? Similarly, should 1.0000000000000000001 be shown as 1.1?

Comment: Perhaps you are confused because rounded values are displayed when a tibble is printed? For example `tibble(Number = c(0.9999))` will display `1.00`, but if you add a glimpse, `tibble(Number = c(0.9999)) %>% glimpse()`, you'll see the true value of the number, `0.9999`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the end of your code %%100 you can add the zeros to your 1 and then you can round as you like.

```
Data <- tibble(Number = c(0.998971282, 0.97871, 0.98121752874, 0.98921752874, 0.91571358, 1)) %%100
Data <- Data %>% summarize(Number = round(Number, 2))
output:
Number
1.00
0.98
0.98
0.99
0.92
1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Data <- tibble(Number = c(0.998971282, 0.97871, 0.98121752874, 0.98921752874, 0.91571358, 1))
Data %>% mutate(Number=round(Number,2))
```

Please refer to this video to learn more about the different rounding commands in R
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSrnWZcv0tc